# comparing other data frames and selecting rows in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a few complicated conditions in my algorithm and I can not handle them. I need help.

I have 4 data frames including index numbers and outputs like

`` u1 = data.frame(index = c(1,3,12,21,24),output =c(1,0,1,0,1), u2 = data.frame(index = c(2,5,16,1),output =c(0,1,1,0)` ,  u3 = data.frame(index = c(1,5,7,16),output =c(0,1,0,0)  , u4 = data.frame(index = c(21,24,8),output =c(0,0,1) ``.

I try to write a `for(i in 1:4)` loop in R (if you can solve without for loop, you are welcome). In each step, the ith loop will check the other data frames index numbers (for instance, in step i=1, check u2, u3, u4) and if any index number is repeated at least 2times in other data frames, I will take it. After that, I will check the output of these same indexes. If outputs of these indexes are same, I will select that index number. let me give an example on my data frames above for i =1;
check the indexes of u2, u3, and u4. Index number 5 is repeated 2 times (outputs are same, 1 ) and I will select it, index number 1 is repeated 2 times and outputs are the same I will select it and index number 16 repeated 2 times but outputs are different that is why I will not select it.

i =2;
check the indexes of u1, u3, and u4...

Thanks.

Comment: @akrun can you check the question? I have edited. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps - get the 'u1', 'u2', ... objects in a `list` ('lst1'), then loop over the `names` of the `list`, subset the `list` without the loop name (`setdiff`), `rbind`, then, get the `table`, create a logical vector based on the frequency count for '1's, extract the `names` based on that, convert the named `list` to a two column data.frame (`stack`)

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^u\\d+$'))
stack(lapply(setNames(names(lst1), names(lst1)), 
    function(u) names(which(table(do.call(rbind, lst1[setdiff(names(lst1), 
    u)]))[,'1'] > 1))))[2:1]
   ind values
1  u1      5
2  u4      5
```

#### data

```
u1 <- structure(list(index = c(1, 3, 12, 21, 24), output = c(1, 0, 
1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

u2 <- structure(list(index = c(2, 5, 16, 1), output = c(0, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

u3 <- structure(list(index = c(1, 5, 7, 16), output = c(0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

u4 <- structure(list(index = c(21, 24, 8), output = c(0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```